# dict.keys() returning dict_keys class - view object expected

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I run the following code in Python 2.7.3 and Python 3.2.3:

```
test_dict = {'foo':'bar'}
type(test_dict.keys())
```

In Python 2 the output is:

```
<type 'list'>
```

In Python 3:

```
<class 'dict_keys'>
```

However the Python 3 documentation states that the `keys` method should return a [view object](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), so why is a class being returned?

Comment: I don't understand the question. `keys` does not return a class, it returns an instance of a class. I think there is some misunderstanding in the usage of `type`. In comparison, `type(1)` returns `<class 'int'>`, and 1 is not a class either.

Comment: I think you're right, I don't understand type

Comment: `dict_keys` is a dict view type. There is more than one such type. `test_dict.values()` would return a `dict_values` instance, `test_dict.items()` returns a `dict_items` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keys` returned a view. It's `type` that returned a class:

```
v this part doesn't return a view
type(test_dict.keys())
               ^this part returns a view
```

`<class 'dict_keys'>` is the type of the view object returned by `test_dict.keys()`. If you want the view itself, don't call `type`.

Answer (score 9):

`keys()` in Python 2 returns a list, which is fine - for small dictionaries, but for large ones this takes time. So in Python 3 it is now a view object, which is iterable. This view object is actually of a type of class called `dict_keys`.

Calling `type()` on `keys()` returns the type of object that the item is, which is why in Python2 it is a `list`, and in Python 3 it is a `dict_keys`.